# Exception message not displayed

Tags: android, exception, httpurlconnection

I have written an Android application in which I allow the user to select an image from the gallery and post it to an Internet server as a Base64 encoded String using HTTP REST-ful web-services upon click of a button.

When the server is up/ running and the phone has a good 3G connection, it works fine. However, if the phone has a bad connection or if the server is down for some reason, then the Android application crashes altogether (screen goes black and application quits).

Although I’ve given a catch block to catch any IO/ other exceptions, the catch block code doesn’t execute if there is an error while executing connection.connect () ; I have tried catching Throwable as well to no avail – the code in the catch block never executes and the application itself stops working.

Can somebody please help me in figuring out how to catch these exceptions which are occurring when the server is not reachable or if there is an error while transmitting the image?

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

if you check (ex as Exception) instead of IOException, maybe it helps

Comment: the OP mentioned s/he has tried catching `Throwable`, which is still more general than `Exception`.